# Pass data from jquery dialog in partial view to main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am new to mvc and to jQuery so I'm not entirely sure how best to phrase this question to get the best response. I'm seeing a number of posts that give me bits of what I need but I'm still not able to put them all together into a working solution.

**EDIT 18 Sep 2013**

I have an mvc4 app that has a number of views that need to lookup a person record from db. What I'm looking fir is a solution that will on the click of button open a jqueryui dialog that will allow user to search db for person rec. I also have views that need to lookup a number of person records to populate the model (ie CaseWorkerPersonID, ParentPersonID, ChildPersonID etc). The dialog is to have a jqueryui autocomplete widget and when the user selects person from autocomplete list then the view that initiated the search dialog needs to have reference to the selected person record.

Cheers

**EDIT**
OK so here is an example of what Im trying to do.

I have a Case/Details ...

```
@model CENSimple.Models.Case
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
//var linkObj;
$(function () {
    $(".editLink").button(); //turn the editLink class links to buttons

    $('#updateDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                //psuedo code
                if(this update from "Add CW to case")
{
                $('#SelectedPersonFromAddCWToCase').text('PersonID: ' + $('#selectedPersonID').val() + ' selected');
} else
{
                $('#SelectedPersonFromAddPersonToCase').text('PersonID: ' + $('#selectedPersonID').val() + ' selected');
}

            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('#selectedPersonID2').text('Person search cancelled');
            }
        }
    });


    $(".editLink").click(function () {

        //change the title of the dialog
        var linkObj = $(this);
        var dialogDiv = $('#updateDialog');
        var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
        $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
            dialogDiv.html(data);
            dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });

});

</script>

}

@Html.ActionLink( "Add person to case", "_AddPersonToCase", new { SearchURL = "/Person/SearchPeople"}, new { @class = "editLink" })
@Html.ActionLink( "Add CW to case", "_AddCWToCase", new { SearchURL = "/Person/SearchPeople2"}, new { @class = "editLink" })

<div id="SelectedPersonFromAddPersonToCase"></div>
<div id="SelectedPersonFromAddCWToCase"></div>

<div id="updateDialog" title="Select Person"></div>
```

and a Case Controller with the following actions that return the _PersonSearch partial view

```
public ActionResult _AddPersonToCase(Models.PersonSearch obj)
{
    return PartialView("_PersonSearch", obj);
}
public ActionResult _AddCWToCase(Models.PersonSearch obj)
{
    return PartialView("_PersonSearch", obj);
}
```

and a Person Controller with the following actions that return JSON data for my jquery autocomplete widget as follows

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Example Search action 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="term">search term from jquery autocomplete</param>
    /// <returns>value/label list of people matching search term
    /// displaying firstname followed by surname 
    /// </returns>
    public JsonResult SearchPeople(string term)
    {
        Repositories.PersonRepository repo = new Repositories.PersonRepository();
        var results=repo.GetSearchResults(new Models.PersonSearchCriteria { Name = term });

        var results1 = results
                        .OrderBy(s => s.FirstName)
                        .Select(s => new 
                        { 
                            label = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName, 
                            value = s.ID 
                        });

        JsonResult r = Json(results1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return r;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Example Search action 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="term">search term from jquery autocomplete</param>
    /// <returns>value/label list of people matching search term
    /// displaying surname followed by firstname
    /// </returns>
    public JsonResult SearchPeople2(string term)
    {
        Repositories.PersonRepository repo = new Repositories.PersonRepository();
        var results = repo.GetSearchResults(new Models.PersonSearchCriteria { Name = term });
        var results1 = results
                        .OrderBy(s => s.FirstName)
                        .Select(s => new
                        {
                            label = s.LastName + ", " + s.FirstName ,
                            value = s.ID
                        });

        JsonResult r = Json(results1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return r;
    }
```

and finally a _PersonSearch partial view as follows...

```
    @model CENSimple.Models.PersonSearch
        <script>

            $(function () {

                $("#Name").autocomplete({

                    source:'@Model.SearchURL',
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {

                        //Put the selected label into the input 
                        //If this is not done then the value will be in input
                        this.value = ui.item.label;

                        $('#SelectedPersonID').val(ui.item.value);
                        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default focus behavior.

                    },
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        this.value = ui.item.label;
                        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default focus behavior.
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>


    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="searchPerson">Name: </label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name)

    </div>

    <div id="searchContext"></div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SelectedPersonID)
```

What I need is the ability to use my _PersonSearch partial view in multiple places in my /Case/Details view

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Add person to case", "_AddPersonToCase", new { SearchURL = "/Person/SearchPeople"}, new { @class = "editLink" })
@Html.ActionLink( "Add CW to case", "_AddCWToCase", new { SearchURL = "/Person/SearchPeople2"}, new { @class = "editLink" })
```

and have each instance of the partial view able to be configured to

1. use the Case action of my choosing
2. use the Person search action of my choosing
3. update an element of my choosing on main view when I have selected a value from the autocomplete widget in my partial view and clicked the Update button.

The code that I have posted gives me this ability to do 1 and 2 but Im stuck on how to satisfy requirement 3

ie populate `<div id="SelectedPersonFromAddPersonToCase"></div>` when Update button in the `"Add person to case"` instance of dialog is clicked and have `<div id="SelectedPersonFromAddCWToCase"></div>` when Update button in the `"Add CW to case"` instance of dialog is selected

All advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive what you're looking for, the request you have on the server that gets the person's record needs to have more added to the DB query so the fields you want are retrieved along with the person's name.

There are things to consider first.  If you want this extra information WITH the autocomplete drop-down results, make sure the server can handle that many requests simultaneously.  If you just want the data for use after selecting the person, add something to act on the click event.  Between a second SELECT query and a second AJAX request, I'm not sure which is harder on performance, sorry.

The library should have an event handler or at least a selector for the list of results that you can initiate action as a result of the record being chosen (for instance - downloading the rest of the details when someone is chosen).

JSON will provide the detailed information to the page and you will take those results and display them as you see fit.

Without the actual code I can't get much more specific here but I hope this helped some.

Comment: Thanks @Deryck.  Ive added a bit more detail to try to show what Im trying to acheive